# R proper way to parse xml

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I have an xml response containing `Body` and `Header` nodes, how can I access the value of the `$Envelope$Body$checkVatResponse$valid` node?

For some reason I already can't find the `Body` using `xml_find_all`

```r
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

body = r'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
             <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
             <soapenv:Header/>
             <soapenv:Body>
             <urn:checkVat  xmlns:urn="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">
             <urn:countryCode>NL</urn:countryCode>
             <urn:vatNumber>800938495B01</urn:vatNumber>
             </urn:checkVat>
             </soapenv:Body>
             </soapenv:Envelope>]'

r <- POST("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatTestService", body = body)
stop_for_status(r)
content(r) %>% xml_find_all('//Body')
content(r) %>% xml2::as_list()
res <- content(r) 

xml_children(res) %>% xml_name()
# [1] "Header" "Body"  
xml_find_all(res,'.//Body')
# {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Comment: remove the leading dot?

Comment: yields `{xml_nodeset (0)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with XML data, you need to be mindful of the namespaces used in the file. You need to previx namespaced nodes with the correct namespace. To extract the `valid` value you can use

```
content(r) %>% xml_find_all('//env:Body/ns2:checkVatResponse/ns2:valid')
```

To see all the namespaces used by the file you can run

```
content(r) %>% xml_ns()
# env <-> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
# ns2 <-> urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types
```